# C++ Format std::chrono::utc_clock to milliseconds

Tags: c++

I use the following line to get the time with ms precision:

```
std::stringstream s;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::utc_clock> TimeTag = time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::utc_clock::now());

s << format("{0:%F}T{0:%TZ}", TimeTag);
```

When I write this to a file the output is (ns precision):
`2024-01-07T17:02:50.214000000Z`

How can I format without the trailing 0s?

Thanks,
Johannes

Every relevant site on WWW tells me use the above instructions, but the result is always with trailing 0s.

Comment: are you using `std::format`? Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 5):

You should specify `duration` for your `time_point`, use `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::utc_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>` (or just `auto` in your example) as the `TimeTag` type.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to truncate the time point to milliseconds, just use `auto` to get a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::utc_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>` since you've already done the `time_point_cast`.

Another option could be to just [`std::chrono::floor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/floor) (or [`std::chrono::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/round)) it when presenting it:

```cpp
auto TimeTag = std::chrono::utc_clock::now();

s << std::format("{0:%F}T{0:%TZ}",
                 std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::milliseconds>(TimeTag)) << '\n';
```

Comment: Also thanks to you.

Your and Jan's answers really showed my lack of understanding the definition of utc_clock, i.e. to also include a "resolution" in the definition....'
With the new knowledge the meaning of the format %T, namely:
"if the precision of the input cannot be exactly represented with seconds, then the format is a decimal floating-point number with a fixed format and a precision matching that of the precision of the input".

I didn't had any clue that the precision is set with the defintion.....